# Removing the SSL Certificate for a Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl

Client has hosted a website in his server and it is https site (https://www.example.com)
He is exposing a webserice which is something like this (https://www.example.com/getitems.asmx). How the SSL certificate might have been installed? Whether it is given for whole website? or is it possible to remove the https for the webservice alone (for example: http://www.example.com/getitems/asmx)?

Kindly help

---

I am not sure about the answer. But my client changed the https:// site to http://. Still don't know how to remove the SSL certificate for webservice :(

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?